How do I turn the equation for a curve in 3d into a parametric function?
I am working on a manim project and wanted to graph the curve of intersection between $\frac{x}{2}-\frac{3y}{4}+\frac{23}{4} = z$ and $\sqrt{x^{3}+x+23-y^{2}} = z$. In order to do this I have to turn it into a parametric function, but to be frank, I have no idea how.
Here is the equation I am trying to parameterize:
$\frac{x}{2}-\frac{3y}{4}+\frac{23}{4}=\sqrt{x^{3}+x+23-y^{2}}=z$
I tried parameterize the 2D projection of the curve ($\frac{x}{2}-\frac{3y}{4}+\frac{23}{4}=\sqrt{x^{3}+x+23-y^{2}}$) but I honestly don't know how, or if it is even possible. I've also seen software that can convert parametric functions into implicit form, I was wondering if there was anything that did the opposite and can help here.

Take $x$ as your parameter. Solve for $y$ using $x$, get $z$ using $x$ and $y$

In the equation $x^3 + x + 23 - y^2= z^2$, you can replace $z$ by $x/2 -3y/4 + 23/4$. This gives you a quadratic equation in the unknown $y$, which you can solve as $y$ in function of $x$, from which you can also express $z$ as a function of $x$, and you have a parametrized curve with $x$ as parameter.
